# I am trying to add Bandit to my gitlab-ci.yml file but on executing an egrep command the job fails without any error message

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The .gitlab-ci.yml file is below, this is the part where I am executing the Test Stage. After running the egrep command, it just fails without any error message

```
  stage: test
  image:
    name: python:latest
    entrypoint:
      - "/usr/bin/env"
      - "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
  script:
    - ls -la
    - python --version
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip
    - pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
    - pip3 install bandit
    - bandit ../lambda_function_code -r | tee ./output_test.log
    - egrep "Severity:\sHigh" output_test.log | wc -l
    - |
      if [ $severity_count -neq 0 ]; then
        exit 1
      fi
    - echo ${TF_ROOT}
```

Pipeline Output (the egrep commaned run successfully, but then after that nothing get runs and the pipeline fails)
[image]

I am trying to find text with Severity: High/medium/low from the output_test.log file generated by the bandit command.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried your command without piping to `wc -l` ? Also, not sure about how gitlab-ci works exactly, but the block after egrep seems very weird

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the output of `egrep "Severity:\sHigh" output_test.log | wc -l` into the `$severity_count` variable.

Try the following:

```yaml
  stage: test
  image:
    name: python:latest
    entrypoint:
      - "/usr/bin/env"
      - "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
  script:
    - ls -la
    - python --version
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip
    - pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
    - pip3 install bandit
    - bandit ../lambda_function_code -r | tee ./output_test.log
    - severity_count=$(egrep "Severity:\sHigh" output_test.log | wc -l)
    - |
      if [ $severity_count -neq 0 ]; then
        exit 1
      fi
    - echo ${TF_ROOT}
```

The `$(...)` around the command tells the script to evaluate the shell statement within the parenthesis.

Comment: @payal Was this helpful? Were you able to make any progress on this problem?